# Yii2 Kartik editable input value will only change after refresh

Tags: ajax, yii2

I use Kartik Editable input widget. I have a `home` model and `tema` model attribute here. Whenever I input  and submit value in the field, the value won't change on-the spot but will only change after I refresh the page instead. What should I do? Thanks!

My controller :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new HomeSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


// table only has one row
$model= Home::find()->one();

    // Check if there is an Editable ajax request
    if (isset($_POST['hasEditable'])) {

        // use Yii's response format to encode output as JSON
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        // read your posted model attributes
        if ($model->load($_POST)) {
            // read or convert your posted information. Based on the 'name' property set in the view. So this 'tema' of $model-> tema comes from 'name' property set in the view.

            $value = $model->tema;
           $model->save();
            // return JSON encoded output in the below format
            return ['output'=>$value, 'message'=>'output berhasil'];

            // alternatively you can return a validation error
            // return ['output'=>'', 'message'=>'Validation error'];
        }
        // else if nothing to do always return an empty JSON encoded output
        else {
            return ['output'=>'', 'message'=>'output gagal'];
        }

        };

return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
    }
```

The view

```
  <?php 

    echo Editable::widget([
    'model' => $model, 
    'attribute' => 'tema',
    'value'=>$model->tema,
/*'asPopover'=>'false',*/
    'type' => 'post',

    'header'=>'tema', 
    'valueIfNull'=>'value-nya NULL',
    'format'=>'link',
    'size'=> 'lg',
    'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
    'editableValueOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success h3']
]);         ?>
```

Another issue, whenever I used `'asPopover'=>'false'`, it shows no error but nothing happen when I click the supposedly editable-input field. The editable-inline field just won't show up. When I use the popOver option,the pop-up just automatically triggered without clicking and also it pop-up on the top left corner of the page. Only after I clicked on the editable widget that triggered the pop-up will it recorrect itself to the proper position. Is it a bug? I used the latest Yii2 with bootstrap 4, and I had set the global parameter in `params.php` config with `'bsVersion' => '4.x',` as in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller, try this:

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new HomeSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    if (isset($_POST['hasEditable'])) 
    {
        $tema = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
        $modelHome = Home::findOne($tema);

        $posted = current($_POST['Home']);
        $post = ['Home' => $posted];

        if ($modelHome->load($post)) {
           $modelHome->save();
           $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$modelHome->tema, 'message'=>'']);
           return $out;

        }
        return;
    };

return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
    }
```